# In how many ways can ww choose $10$ cards so there are $3$ exact matches?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $20$ cards- $10$ reds numbered $1,2,\cdots,10$, and $10$ blues numbered $1,2, \cdots, 10$. In how many ways can 10 cards be picked to so that there are EXACTLY 3 MATCHES- where a match means a red card and blue card have the same number.

What I did:
Number of ways to get 3 or more matches - Number of ways to get 4 matches or more, that is:

$\dbinom{10}{3} \cdot \dbinom{14}{4} - \dbinom{10}{4}\cdot \dbinom{12}{2}$

Can someone point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to pick the cards that will make up the three matching pairs. That is a component of your answer, so I will assume that part is clear to you. Now we count the number of ways to pick the remaining $4$ cards.

There remain $7$ "couples." We pick $4$ of these, and for each couple we choose the colour that will be used. That can be done in $\binom{7}{4}2^4$ ways, for a total of $\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{4}2^4$.

**Remark:** About your answer, the issue is about the count of "bad" choices, where there are $4$ or more matches. This number is not $\binom{10}{4}\binom{12}{2}$. That expression "double-counts" the $5$ matches situations. For the $\binom{10}{4}$ part counts, among others, the situations where we picked each of the couples $1,2,3,4$, while the $\binom{12}{2}$ counts among others the situations where we picked couple $5$. But $\binom{10}{4}$ also includes picking couples $1,2,3,5$, and $\binom{12}{2}$ counts among others picking couple $4$. Thus picking the $5$ couples has been double-counted, indeed multiple-counted.

Comment: I don't quite get the second part of your answer.

Comment: Do you mean the remark at the end about what goes wrong with your formula?

Comment: &#233;Nicolas no, your answer

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think it will be $\binom{10}{4}$ instead of $\binom{10}{2}$.

Comment: Actually, I am not able to follow the whole of your answer.

Comment: We need to pick $4$ more people, making sure there will not be a matching couple. So we choose the couples who will send a representative. There are $7$ couples left. There are $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to choose which couples (numbers) will be represented. Once we have chosen the numbers, we line them up in order, and for each chosen number we choose red or blue.

Comment: @shauryagupta: Thank you, you are referring to the next to last line of the remark. Fixed.

Comment: @Andr&#233;Nicolas That explains it well. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Your strategy of removing the bad ones (Inclusion/Exclusion) will also work, except that there is one term missing. It is, however, somewhat more complicated, Inclusion/Exclusion arguments can be tricky.